# sql where with between clause on col type date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to make search query 
query accept parameter from asp.net web application

when @firstName search properly but not working with between clause

```
 create proc test 
    @From Datetime,
    @to Datetime,
    @firstName varchar(50) 
    as 
    begin 
    select * from Employee 
    where Empfname=(case when @firstName != '' then @firstName else Empfname end) 
    and 1=(case when @From != null and @From != '' and @to != null and @to != '' 
    then EmpJoinDate between @From and @to else 1 end) end
```

Comment: Don't use `case` in the where clause, switch to `and`/`or` instead. (Something like `where (@firstName = '' or @firstName = Empfname) ...`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would encourage you to be consistent in the use of "wildcards".  Your code seems to confuse empty strings and `NULL`.  Just use the convention that a `NULL` value means anything is allowed.

Then, remove the `case` from the `where` clause and explicitly list out the logic.  Here is one method:

```
create proc test (
    @From Datetime,
    @to Datetime,
    @firstName varchar(50) 
) as 
begin 
    select e.*
    from Employee e
    where (Empfname = @firstName or @firstname is null) and
          ((@from is null and @to is null) or
           (@from is null and EmpJoinDate <= @to) or
           (@to is null and EmpJoinDate >= @from) or
           (EmpJoinDate >= @from and EmpJoinDate <= @to)
          );
end;
```

Then, you should revisit the need for a stored procedure.  What you have is really more appropriate for a table-valued function.

Answer (score 0):

Replace case-based comparisons. Instead of

```
Empfname=(case when @firstName != '' then @firstName else Empfname end)
```

write

```
(@firstName='' OR Empfname=@firstName)
```

Instead of

```
1=(case when @From != null ...
```

write

```
 (@From='' OR @To='' OR EmpJoinDate BETWEEN convert(datetime, @From)
 AND convert(datetime, @To))
```

**Note:** If you are using `NULL` values for your parameters in place of empty strings `''`, do not apply `=` and `!=` operators to them, because they do not work. Instead, use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators.

Comment: query not returns all the records when parameters are empty

Comment: @user2561115 Are you passing empty strings or `NULL`s?

Comment: dasblinkenlight i am passing null

Comment: @user2561115 Then you need to replace all xyz='' with xyz is null expressions.

Answer (score 0):

My syntax isn't exactly correct as I don't know the database you are targeting. In general I would change the arguments to not null (required), test for any one or more empty strings, where if this passes then execute your parameterized SQL.

```
    create proc test 
    @From Datetime not null,
    @to Datetime not null,
    @firstName varchar(50) not null
    as 
    begin 
       If @From != '' or @To != '' or @FirstName != '' 
           select * from Employee 
           where Empfname= @firstName
           and  EmpJoinDate between @From and @to 
       end if
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The target database is posted as a tag in the question.

Answer (score 0):

try fixing your procedure to this one:

```
-- test '20160101','20160810', 'z'
alter proc test 
    @From Datetime,
    @to Datetime,
    @firstName varchar(50)

as
DECLARE @DateCondition varchar(100),
        @FNameCondition VARCHAR(200),
        @SQLStr VARCHAR(2000)

begin 
    IF @From <> '' AND @To <> ''
        SET @DateCondition = ' EmpJoinDate between ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@From) + ''' and ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@To) + ''''

    IF  @firstName != '' 
        SET @FNameCondition = '''' + @firstName + ''''
    ELSE  
        SET @FNameCondition = ' Empfname '

    SET @SQLStr = '    
    select * from Employee 
    where Empfname= ' + @FNameCondition + '
    and ' + @DateCondition

    PRINT (@SQLStr)
    EXEC (@SQLStr)

END
Go
```

Comment: The use of dynamic SQL is a clever approach.  However, proposing such a solution by putting the parameters directly into the query string is irresponsible, because it makes the code subject to syntax errors and SQL injection attacks.  The correct approach uses parameters and `sp_executesql`.

Comment: I thought i made it as a procedure that accepts external parameters